# Modems WAN IP address is different than routers WAN IP address

Tags: router, ip, modem, wan

So first off I'm not having any connection issues whatsoever.  Just been trying to self learn more about networking when I noticed this situation.

I have a residential wireless gateway device leased by Comcast - Model: Cisco 3939 XB3.

I have this set up in bridge mode to an Asus RT-N66R router - Firmware version 3.0.0.4.382_50702

I was just kind of messing around looking through all of the settings and I just happened to notice that my WAN IP address on the Comcast modem (keep in mind is now acting in bridge mode) is providing a WAN IP address of 75.69.25.xx and my Asus router is showing a WAN IP address of 73.114.17.xx.  Neither of these IP addresses are local IP addresses.  I'm just confused as to why they might be different.  If I look them both up on arin.net they are both owned by Comcast.

So again - no problems with connection just curious.

Appreciate any info, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the Comcast modem have any router functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't they be different?

The addresses need to be different for the simple reason that you can't have the same address assigned to multiple devices – if you did, you'd have no way to distinguish which device will receive the packets.

(Though it does sound *unusual* that the Cisco device is still assigning itself multiple addresses; it's not what I would expect from bridge mode, and I'd sure like to see its configuration screens... But besides that, there's nothing technically *wrong* about it.)